# Angular factory not returning data from Soundcloud (SC.get) request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, soundcloud

I am trying to return data taken from a soundcloud get request with an angular factory so that i can use that data within a controller.

```
app.factory('soundcloud', function() {
    SC.initialize({
        client_id: 'd977aa793080e7656a3b73f35a27406f',
        redirect_uri: 'http://soundcloud.dev/soundcloud.html'
    });
    var data;
    SC.get('/users/kavverhouzer', function(data) {
        data = data;
    });
    return data;
});
```

When i try to log the data within a controller i get 'undefined'. This is the controller:

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, soundcloud) {
    console.log(soundcloud)
});
```

Is there some way to wait until the data has loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [$q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q)

Which will set up a promise.

EDIT:

maybe something like:

```
app.factory('soundcloud', function($q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    SC.initialize({
        client_id: 'd977aa793080e7656a3b73f35a27406f',
        redirect_uri: 'http://soundcloud.dev/soundcloud.html'
    });

    SC.get('/users/kavverhouzer', function(data) {
       deferred.resolve( data);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
});
```

Comment: I'm reading the docs atm, thanks for that. But when try the code you gave me it's giving me an object you can see here: http://j.blck.lv/image/1w0g0f170i3t, what do i do with that?

Comment: The object is the response. Read up on the paradigm of promises and it will save your day when you catch on.

Comment: To be more helpful.
The object that you get back, you can do a `.then(function(data){
//Do stuff with data.
})